# Play animator on collider enter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have wrote a code that semi-works for me. Everything works aside from working animation.

What I'm trying to do is that when Player enters trigger, and if he/she presses E it will perform an animation. (Animation is working fine btw, so it's just code error?).

Here's what I got so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class barTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    // press shit to drink text
    public GameObject drinkText;

    // bottle
    public GameObject alcBottle;

    // drink animator
    public GameObject animatorOjbect;
    Animator drinkAmin;

    public bool triggerIsOn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        drinkAmin = animatorOjbect.GetComponent<Animator> ();

        drinkText.SetActive(false);
        alcBottle.SetActive(false);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

        triggerIsOn = true;

        if (other.gameObject.name == "vThirdPersonController") {
            drinkText.SetActive (true);

        }

        if (triggerIsOn && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {

            drinkAmin.Play ("Dab");
            alcBottle.SetActive (true);
        }


    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){

        if (other.gameObject.name == "vThirdPersonController") {
            drinkText.SetActive (false);
            alcBottle.SetActive (false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Debug.Log` to make sire that the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` functions are even called.

Comment: @Programmer duh. Tested that already.

Comment: Im sorry I can’t help you, but the comment on the GameObject drinkText, is just wonderful. Best I can suggest is set a breakpoint in OnTriggerEnter and see what the value of triggerIsOn is when you press E. Follow the logic and see if it’s being reset somewhere else?

Comment: @BrienFoss I've been trying for past few. Otherwise, I would've not asked anyone. Heh, glad you liked //

Comment: Ok see my answer. The Debug.Log should help you if you run into issues. It's worth doing that in your future questions so that you can tell us what exactly is causing the problem by either showing us the log or telling us the problem by looking at the logs yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnTriggerEnter` is called once and it will be hard to get press the E button and get `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` to detect that at the-same time. Checking the E input in the [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) function is more appropriate for this but `OnTriggerStay` does not work sometimes so count it out. Although it's worth knowing that it exist.

Move `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` to the `Update` function which is called *every frame* then set it to `true` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function and `false` in the `OnTriggerExit` function. Below are the code that should be changed.

```
void Update()
{
    if (triggerIsOn && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        Debug.Log("E button pressed");
        drinkAmin.Play("Dab");
        alcBottle.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "vThirdPersonController")
    {
        Debug.Log("Detected vThirdPersonController");
        triggerIsOn = true;
        drinkText.SetActive(true);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{

    if (other.gameObject.name == "vThirdPersonController")
    {
        Debug.Log("Lost vThirdPersonController");
        triggerIsOn = false;

        drinkText.SetActive(false);
        alcBottle.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Once you get that working, starting using the `CompareTag` function instead of `gameObject.name` as that is more proficient.

Comment: Ah. That makes so much sense now. I forgot that it would've worked just for 1 frame and it's nearly impossible yet impractical to to use the way I did.

Comment: It works just the way I wanted it to work. Off I go to implement the rest. Thanks buddy,  I really appreciate it. Happy Christmas Eve! <3

Comment: No problem. You must be extremely  fast to get it work that way but I have never gotten it to work that way when I made that same mistake the past. Happy coding!

Comment: After comparing your piece of code to mine, I understood the issue. Yet, I've basically copy pasted your code and it seem to be working fine. I just have to clean a code a bit to make it more simple but I believe this is exactly logic it should follow. Thanks again. By the way, I remember your nickname. You've helped me before. Is it just 1 person or the whole team? :D

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, I have helped you before and I am one person. I simply chose the screen name "Programmer". You will see me a lot if your question has the Unity3d tag.

Comment: fair enough, and damn, nice! Thanks again. Cheers