# How Do I Destroy The Collided GameObject When The Pickup Button Is Pressed (X) In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to make my GameObject (pickup) get destroyed when the player enters its trigger and presses x to pick it up.

This is what I've got so far.
this is on the pickup that needs to be destroyed:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (UIManager.XButtonPressed == true)
    {
        UIManager.AbleTopickUp = false;
        UIManager.XButtonPressed = false;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Debug.Log("Destroyed the pickup.");
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        UIManager.AbleTopickUp = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        UIManager.AbleTopickUp = true;
    }
}
```

and this is on the Player That Is Colliding with the Pickup's Trigger:

```
if (UIManager.AbleTopickUp)
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("XButton"))
    {
        UIManager.XButtonPressed = true;
        if (currentSlot == 1)
        {
            Slot1_W = 1;
        }

        if (currentSlot == 2)
        {
            Slot2_W = 1;
        }

        if (currentSlot == 3)
        {
            Slot3_W = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Because `OnTriggerEnter` is only called for a single frame: the frame the two colliders touch. If you don't hit the button on exactly that frame, nothing happens. There's a dupe around somewhere.

Comment: Foudn it. [Play animator on collider enter (Unity3d/c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958805/play-animator-on-collider-enter-unity3d-c)

Comment: so...what does happen in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `OnTriggerEnter` with `OnTriggerStay`

Comment: According to the Unity docs... "OnTriggerStay is called on 'all physics updates' for every collider other that is touching the trigger"... Wouldn't destroying a gameObject that number of cause performance issues...??

Comment: Not really in your script you destroy the script carrying object itself so once it's destroyed there's no script to call it.

If you were destroying another object you would have a `NullReference` error but you won't have that here. Also even if destroy is called every physics update devices nowadays can handle it very well also you can set the interval in which physics updates are called in `Edit > Project Settings > Time > Fixed Timestep` even though I wouldn't recommend this so Good luck and don't forget to give me that sweet sweet green tick :) thanks.